# How to start using the thousands separator in pgfplots for numbers >= 10000 only?

Tags: pgfplots, spacing, formatting

When using a half space (`\,`) as the thousangs separator it is common to only start using it for numbers larger than 10000. This is reflected, e.g., in the siunitx package:

- `\SI{1000}` becomes 1000
- `\SI{12345}` becomes 12 345

However, pgfplots appears to only offer

`\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={\,}}`

which adapts the thousands separator for all groups of three digits.
Is there a way to change this behavior, matching the one specified above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,int detect,1000 sep={\,},min exponent for 1000 sep=4}
```

Check the page 33 of this document http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf. Hope I've helped you!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,int detect,1000 sep={\,},min exponent for 1000 sep=4}
\pgfmathprintnumber{1000};
\pgfmathprintnumber{10000}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Seems like a good answer. Please add an MWE to allow easy testing, and you'll have my upvote.

Comment: I updated the answer `@frougon`. Hope it works!

Comment: Yes, though I would replace the two lines`\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}` with just `\usepackage{pgf}`. (BTW, `compat=1.9` seems very old). Maybe the OP will need an example that affects only the tick labels of a plot... but it's the OP's fault not to have provided a MWE with a plot. Thanks for this update, anyway.

Comment: I usually use `pgfplots` with `compat=1.9` because I have some problems with the latest versions with old graphs, but yeah, you are right!